# ui-sref passing parameters to new tab

Tags: angularjs

I am using $stateProvider and in my html I am using an ui-sref

```html
<a ui-sref="page/info({IDF: 4199})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">{{row.Desc}}</a>
```

But if I click to open a new tab, the system will open a new tab on the correct page, but without the parameters, is there anything I can do to send the parameters too?

```js
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/index.html'
  })  
  .state('page/info', {
      url: '/page/info',
      templateUrl: 'views/page/info.html',
      params: {
          IDF: null
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass parameter this way.

```
<a ui-sref="page/info({IDF: row.id})">
```

For more info:https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/index.html'
  })  
  .state('page/info', {
      url: '/page/info/:IDF',
      templateUrl: 'views/page/info.html'
  })
```

Comment: Yes, I used that because I built the object in my controller, but if I to do like yours it's not work too.
The new page not receive the parameters.

Comment: Show your corresponding state definition in config?